# Strapi - prevent 'draft' content from being available to unauthenticated user

Tags: strapi

I am (happily) using the GraphQL endpoint, but need to prevent content that is being written from being available to unauthenticated users until the author moves that content from 'draft' to 'published' status.

How can I cause the GraphQL endpoint to filter out content, for example, based on one of its fields?

Thanks!